# How to generate quarterly report and sum by each quarter in a year in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to generate a quarterly report and sum by each quarter in a year in mysql database. I have written the below query and its not working

```
SELECT t.name as terminals, 
    sum(bl.barrels_net_qty) as 'IST QTR', 
    sum(bl2.barrels_net_qty) as '2ND QTR', 
    sum(bl3.barrels_net_qty) as '3RD QTR', 
    sum(bl4.barrels_net_qty) as '4TH QTR', 
    sum(coalesce(bl.barrels_net_qty,0)) 
+ sum(coalesce(bl2.barrels_net_qty,0)) 
+ sum(coalesce(bl3.barrels_net_qty,0))
+ sum(coalesce(bl4.barrels_net_qty,0)) as total 
FROM loadingdetails  as l
LEFT JOIN bldetails as bl on bl.operation_no = l.operation_no AND l.year = '2020' AND bl.month = 'January' and bl.month = 'Feburary' and bl.month = 'March'
LEFT JOIN bldetails as bl2 on bl2.operation_no = l.operation_no  and l.year = '2020' AND bl2.month = 'April' and bl2.month = 'May' and bl2.month = 'June'  AND l.month = 'April' and bl2.month = 'May' and bl2.month = 'June'
LEFT JOIN bldetails as bl3 on bl3.operation_no = l.operation_no  and l.year = '2020' AND bl3.month = 'July' and bl3.month = 'August' and bl3.month = 'September'
LEFT JOIN bldetails as bl4 on bl4.operation_no = l.operation_no and l.year = '2020' AND bl4.month = 'October' and bl4.month = 'November' and bl4.month = 'December'
LEFT JOIN terminals as t on t.id = l.terminal_id
GROUP BY t.name
```

Below is the output.

[image]

Comment: define "it's not working". What is your intention with that SQL and what does the query actually give you? Please provide a [Minimal Complete Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue. Thanks

Comment: You must use `terminals` table as the first table in joining chain. Or use RIGHT JOIN for it.

Comment: The terminals table only keeps lists of all the terminals and is referenced and the its id is referenced in the loadingdetails table.

Comment: @Akina why do you say this?

Comment: @Martin Look at GROUP BY expression.

Comment: You cannot have a month which is jan AND feb.

Comment: @Akina yes, but you have done nothing to explain why you state what you state, for people who do not understand simply looking at the "Group By" clause (such as the Original Poster)

Comment: @Martin This is a comment. If it is unclear for OP he may ask about explanations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be rewritten using conditional aggregation and should be driven from terminals since it is not safe to assume the loading details contains all terminals.

```
SELECT t.name as terminals, 
    sum(case when bl.month in ('January','February','march') then bl.barrels_net_qty else 0 end) as 'IST QTR', 
    sum(case when bl.month in ('April','May','June') then bl.barrels_net_qty else 0 end) as '2ND QTR', 
    sum(case when bl.month in ('July','AUgust','September') then bl.barrels_net_qty else 0 end) as '3RD QTR', 
    sum(case when bl.month in ('October','November','December') then bl.barrels_net_qty else 0 end) as '4TH QTR', 
    sum(coalesce(bl.barrels_net_qty,0))  as total 
FROM terminals as t 
left loadingdetails  as l on t.id = l.terminal_id
LEFT JOIN bldetails as bl on bl.operation_no = l.operation_no AND l.year = '2020' 
GROUP BY t.name ;
```